# Button click using selenium webdriver youtbe example

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findelement

When I run the code, it opens the browser, but I want to click the reject all button when the cookie banner comes from YouTube. I tried using class and a link text. It did not work.

I will appreciate any help.

[image]
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\donner\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(100)
continue_link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Reject all")
continue_link.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(100)
content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '.style-scope.ytd-button-renderer.style-primary size-default')
content.click()
```

Comment: I can not see the cookie banner it's not implemented in my region yet. Can you share the `HTML` source for the banner, also check it could be inside the `iframe`

Comment: Hello @Akzy, I have attached a screen of the banner html reject all button

Comment: I have added the answer, let us know this does not work

Comment: Hey @Akzy I tried it, it did not work. Do you have any selenium webdriver automation code example? For example, going to a website and clicking on different buttons using class or css...

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below `xpath` with the given `code`

```
//*[normalize-space()='Reject all']
```

**OR**

```
//*[contains(text(),'Reject all')]
```

**The Code:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))

element.click();
```

*The above soultion work if there is no* `iframe`

*In case there is `iframe`, than you need to follow below*

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "yourXpath").click()
```